# How does Cassandra's CAS feature interact with consistency levels?

Tags: cassandra

How does [Cassandra's CAS](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-5062) feature in 2.0 interact with consistency levels?  Does a CAS operation honor the consistency level, e.g. LOCAL_QUORUM, so it won't talk to remote DCs, or does it always include remote DCs?

If LOCAL_QUORUM will only work in the one DC, then is it possible for two distinct CAS operations on to be operating simultaneously on the same row key in two data centers?

If a consistency level of ONE is used, then does CAS only use a single node?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The CL in CAS is the CL for the commit.

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-5797 is open for allowing DC-local CAS.